# Reset Time During Run on Life Fitness CLST Integrity Treadmill

Tags: running, treadmill

I’m trying to do a six-minute mile. I’ve found the CLST treadmills take 25 seconds to get up to ten miles per hour. But if it takes that long to get up to speed, I’m losing time/seconds at the very start.

I just want to restart/reset/clear the timer, once up to speed, so I can get a true measurement of my ability (and photo of the control panel with my time and stats accurately displayed.)

The timer starts on it’s own when you quick start, and there’s no obvious button on the panel to start or restart it.

This is a question about machine operation. I looked in the PDF, and can not for the life of me find where that would be, but I may have missed it...

Comment: Can you not just start the timer after it reaches the desired speed? I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking how to operate this particular treadmill? If so, you have a better chance of just finding the manual for the product instead. There's always a PDF version of manuals nowadays, in my experience.

Comment: The timer starts on it’s own when you quick start, and there’s no obvious button on the panel to start or restart it.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question.

Comment: Not sure you can override that, as it's a safety feature. It's hard to go from zero to X in a short amount of time with an artificially moving surface. What is the reason you can't start your six minutes once you get up to speed? If it takes 25 seconds to get up to 10 mpg, and in that time your treadmills "travels" .04 miles, then you have until 6:25 to get to 1.04. Or for a true 6 minute mile (Which would include initial acceleration) go find a track.

Comment: Does the timer start later if you use "Manual" mode instead of "Quick Start"?

Comment: I will check that.